# Need help parsing Dict with facebook graph api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Good evening, I have been working to parse this json and it seems very easy, however, the last few lines, around the comments variable, the only thing I can do is do a for loop and output all the data, I would like for all the data to be like the "Whom" and "post" variable results...  Parsed with just the comments...  Thanks for the help...

```
import facebook
token = "valid access token"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
# pages = ['Shitty']
profile = graph.get_object("55555555555555555")
# this line would connect us to the facebook profile

whom = graph.get_connections("me", connection_name="feed", fields="from")
for who in whom['data']:
    print who['from']['name']

posts = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name="feed")
for post in posts['data']:
    print post['message']

comments = graph.get_connections('me', connection_name="feed",   fields="comments")
for comment in comments['data']:
    print comment
```

Here are the results I get when I run the above command...

```
Davy Wyatt
Johnathan Tate
Jason Owens
Cuzzo keep it pushing
We READY!!!
Hello World
What's up man?

{u'id': u'122457118238072_141638009653316'}
{u'id': u'122457118238072_141637659653351'}
{u'id': u'1924167861201761_1924171591201388'}
{u'id': u'122457118238072_141458699671247'}
{u'id': u'122457118238072_141081529708964',  u'data': [{u'created_time':   u'2016-12-10T14:30:53+0000', u'message': u"What's good big homie?", u'from':     {u'name': u'JasonOwens', u'id': u'10157863582670223'}, u'id': u'141081529708964_141449913005459'}, {u'created_time': u'2016-12-10T18:09:00+0000', u'message': u"hmm, so posts have comments, with messages, with comments and messages within them.  That's quite confusing...", u'from':     {u'name': u'Jason Owens', u'id': u'10157863582670223'}, u'id':     u'141081529708964_141647769652340'}]}}
{u'id': u'122457118238072_141072773043173'}
{u'id': u'122457118238072_139707389846378'}
```

Comment: That's not JSON but a Python 2 dictionary. There's no need to parse it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, basically, I meant the dict doesn't return any data when I print the comment['message'] object, but I know it's there, because when i loop through the comments['data'] object, you can see the message returned within the data.  Neither "message" nor "created_time" will show up, but the data is there...

Comment: Actually, I guess you answered my question with that comment.  I should just iterate over it and use the key and values to get what I want.  Thanks!